# 3 columns, display a div instead of the last column and find the last line graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, meteor

I have 3 colums and I would like to display a form in place of the last column while keeping my responsive page. I can create several lines dynamically with Jquery. For now my div is below the grid. Is it possible at the click of a button to display a form on the right?

```
<div class="addLine">
    <div class="row" >
       <div class="col-md-4">
        {{>graph1}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        {{>graph2}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
          {{> graph3}}
      </div>
    </div>  
   </div>
   <div class="showForm"> {{>form}}</div>
</div>

<template name="graph1">
  <div class="zone" id="zone-0_1" >
    <svg class ="insert" id="graphItem0_1" with="300" height="300"></svg>
      <p class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" id="form"></p>
    </div>
</template>

<template name="graph2">
    <div class="zone" id="zone-0_2" >
      <svg class ="insert" id="graphItem0_2" with="300" height="300"></svg>
      <p class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" id="form"></p>
    </div>
</template>


<template name="graph3">
    <div class="zone" id="zone-0_3">
      <svg class ="insert" id="graphItem0_3" with="300" height="300"></svg>
      <p class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" id="form"></p>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS `visibility` property. Set it for `hidden` by default and make `visible` by clicking.

Comment: Yes at the moment I use this solution but it's not beautiful, because I can insert others colums in my grid and now if I've 3 lines, I need to scroll my page to look my form. :/ . It's not the best solution.